# How Extract Obstacle Information?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I configured my non static map, but I have not figured out how to read information on obstacles. The type of topic (/move_base_node/local_costmap/obstacles) is nav_msgs::GridCells ?

I could use occupancy grid ?

thanks

```
#Independent settings for the planner's costmap
global_costmap:
    publish_voxel_map: true
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    update_frequency: 2.5
    publish_frequency: 1.0
    static_map: false
    rolling_window: true
    width: 20.0
    height: 20.0
    resolution: 0.05
    origin_x: 0.0
    origin_y: 0.0

#Independent settings for the local costmap
local_costmap:
    publish_voxel_map: true
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    update_frequency: 5.0
    publish_frequency: 2.0
    static_map: false
    rolling_window: true
    width: 10.0
    height: 10.0
    resolution: 0.05
    origin_x: 0.0
    origin_y: 0.0
map_type: costmap
transform_tolerance: 0.2
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
inflation_radius: 0.25

observation_sources: base_scan

#base_scan_marking: {sensor_frame: base_scan_link,
#                    data_type: PointCloud2,
#                    topic: /base_scan/marking,
#                    expected_update_rate: 0.2,
#                    observation_persistence: 0.0,
#                    marking: true,
#                    clearing: false,
#                    min_obstacle_height: 0.06,
#                    max_obstacle_height: 2.0}

base_scan: {sensor_frame: base_laser_front_link,
            data_type: LaserScan,
            topic: /base_scan,
            expected_update_rate: 0.2,
            observation_persistence: 0.0,
            marking: true,
            clearing: true,
            min_obstacle_height: -0.10,
            max_obstacle_height: 2.0}

#change this
footprint: [[0.26, 0.18],
            [0.26, 0.014],
            [0.31, 0.014],
            [0.31, -0.014],
            [0.26, -0.014],
            [0.26, -0.18],
            [-0.27, -0.18],
            [-0.27, 0.18]]

controller_frequency: 10.0
controller_patience: 15.0
clearing_radius: 0.25
footprint_padding: 0.03
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150111/how-extract-obstacle-information-?/) by [mrshifo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14531/mrshifo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-08**:
You have a problem with reading topic /move_base_node/local_costmap/obstacles? Is it epty or something else? Did not quite understand the question.

**Comment by [mrshifo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14531/mrshifo/) on 2014-04-09**:
This is my code for read where are the obstacles:
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/GridCells.h"

void chatterCallback(const nav_msgs::GridCells::ConstPtr& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("width: [%f]", msg->cell_width);
ROS_INFO("height: [%f]", msg->cell_height);
ROS_INFO("size: [%f]", msg->cells.size());
ROS_INFO("pos_x: [%f]", msg->cells[0].x);     // segmentation fault if there are not obstacle's
ROS_INFO("pos_y: [%f]", msg->cells[0].y);
ROS_INFO("pos_z: [%f]", msg->cells[0].z);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/move_base_node/local_costmap/obstacles", 1000, chatterCallback);

ros::spin();

### return 0;
}

The Problem is:
if there are not obstacles:

- return segmentation fault
- width = 0.05 height =0.05 size =0.0000
  how can I know the size of the array cells[] ? I would like to know if there are obstacles and where

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-09**:
msg->cells.size() ? You already have it in your code.

**Comment by [mrshifo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14531/mrshifo/) on 2014-04-09**:
Yes but msg->cells.size() don't return the dimension of the array !!

So how can I know the last index of the array cells[] ?

( https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e61wd46v4201jg/screen.png )

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-09**:
msg->cells[] is one-dimensional array, as far as i see. So, if msg->cells.size() == 0, then there are no obstacles. If msg->cells.size()>0, then the last index of array == msg->cells.size()-1. In your code you always read first member in array (cells[0]).

**Comment by [mrshifo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14531/mrshifo/) on 2014-04-09**:
Thank you very much,
but why  ROS_INFO("size: [%f]", msg->cells.size());  return size = 0.05000 when there are obstacles ?
the msg->cells.size() should return the number of cells occupied by obstacles but it did not happen.

**Comment by [mrshifo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14531/mrshifo/) on 2014-04-10**:
Right !! Thank you very much, return the correct value.

But I have noticed that sometimes the information remain obstacles in the map. I attach photos and configuration files. I do not understand why.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bxzlid7e25mwuu/obstacle_remain.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bxzlid7e25mwuu/obstacle_remain.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eu7xq4nzpbdrjeb/base_laser.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygvetcp7j2yspuu/config.txt
thanks

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-10**:
It's hard to say why: cannot corellate rviz and sim images on https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bxzlid7e25mwuu/obstacle_remain.png. Can you add laser visualisation in rviz?

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-14**:
It's hard to say why: cannot corellate rviz and sim images on https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bxzlid7e25mwuu/obstacle_remain.png. Can you add laser visualisation in rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cells.size() has int type.

Try use ROS_INFO("size: [%d]", msg->cells.size());  Not %f.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) with karma: 123 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1